# $L^1$ spaces of different measures

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

For two different measures $\mu,\nu$ (finite for simplicity) on the same space $X$, when can we claim that $L^1(X,\mu)\neq L^1(X,\nu)$?

Of course, if $\mu,\nu$ are linearly dependent this fails, but is this the only case? Meaning, is
$$L^1(X,\mu)=L^1(X,\nu)\iff \exists \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\ \mu=\alpha\nu$$true for any $\mu,\nu$?

Edit: Brian suggested in the comment below that $\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}\nu}$ both bounded and bounded away from zero is sufficient for $L^1(\mu)=L^1(\nu)$. Is it also necessary? (we assume both $\mu,\nu$ are positive)

Comment: Let $X=[0,1],$ and $\lambda$ equal to Legesgue measure. Define $\mu(E)=\lambda(E\cap [0,1/2]),$ $\nu(E)=\lambda(E\cap [1/2,1]).$ Then $0$ is the only function in both spaces

Comment: More generally, we would have $L^1(X,\mu) = L^1(X,\nu)$ if both $\mu,\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to one another and the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is both bounded and bounded away from zero.  I as yet don't know if this is necessary, but it _is_ more general than your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

For $\Sigma=\{\emptyset,S,S^{c},X\}$ and $\mu(S)=1/2$, $\mu(S^{c})=1/2$ and $\nu(S)=1/3$, $\nu(S^{c})=2/3$, clearly $\mu\ne\alpha\nu$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ but $L^{1}(X,\Sigma,\mu)=L^{1}(X,\Sigma,\nu)=\text{span}\{0,1,\chi_{S},\chi_{S^{c}}\}$.

Comment: This indeed answers the second question. But what about the first? When can we claim $L^1(\mu)=L^1(\nu)$

Comment: As @Brian Moehring noted that Radon-Nikodym provides one direction, I have no idea for the other direction neither.